# How to add equal width and equal height constraints programmatically in swift?

Tags: swift, nslayoutconstraint

Could anyone help me I have this simple view that is very simple to do if I'm using story board but all of my UILabel is based on somewhere(API) that is why I need to create my view programmatically.

this is the view I would like to achieved

[image]

what I accomplished at the moment are pinning the top label in its position and adding leading space on label 1, 2, & 3

basically what i need are:

1. pin the label 1 to the top label
2. pin the label 3 to bottom
3. add vertical spaces to label 1,2,3
4. have equal width and height constraint in label 1,2 ,3

this is my code so far.

```
 private func addTopConstraint(from:AnyObject,to:AnyObject,cons:CGFloat){
   let topConstraint =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: from, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: to, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: cons)
    self.view.addConstraint(topConstraint)
}

private func addVerticalSpace(from:AnyObject,to:AnyObject,cons:CGFloat){
    let verticalSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: from, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: to, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: cons)

    self.view.addConstraint(verticalSpace)
}
private func addLeadingSpace(from:AnyObject,to:AnyObject,cons:CGFloat){
    let leadingSpace = NSLayoutConstraint(item: from, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: to, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: cons)
    self.view.addConstraint(leadingSpace)
}




 private func sameWidthAndHeight (from:AnyObject,to:AnyObject){
           let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: from, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: to, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
           let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: from, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: to, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
            
            self.view.addConstraint(width)
            self.view.addConstraint(height)
        }
```

but the `sameWidthAndHeight` and `addVerticalSpace` function fails

maybe it something to do with content hugging and priorities too, I'm not that sure since we're used to do this in storyboard.

could anyone share a thought? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have been using a table view with cells, as there you can accommodate different type of cells and also any number of rows as needed. All you need to worry is setting up constraints within the cell that are needed by internal items in the cell, not between 2 cells, etc.

Comment: no, I can't use tableview this is just my initial view I will add many stuff later.

Comment: I need the same thing :(